# Pow Powder Weird Output Message

Tags: ruby, rack-pow, powder

When I do `powder up` I get

```
Expected string default value for '--browser'; got false (boolean)
Pow has been started.
```

What does this mean? I'm having some configuration issues and I've never seen this before. (I'm talking about the first line obviously)

Comment: There's a pull request open on the powder repo to fix this but it hasn't been merged yet: https://github.com/rodreegez/powder/pull/128